# Did Lord Vishnu have 3 wives?

Tags: vishnu

[image: google search screenshot]

> Goddess Sarasvati, by the standard mythological authorities, is the wife of Lord Brahma. The Vaishnavas of Bengal have a popular legend that she was the wife of Lord Vishnu, as were also Goddess Lakshmi and Gangā. The ladies disagreed, goddess Sarasvati, like the other type of learned ladies, Minerva, being something of a termagant; and Lord Vishnu, finding that one wife was as much as even a god could manage, transferred goddess Sarasvati to Lord Brahma and Gangā to Lord Siva, and contented himself with goddess Lakshmi alone.

https://www.google.co.in/amp/www.speakingtree.in/allslides/did-lord-brahma-marry-his-own-daughter/m-lite

Comment: This question could be greatly improved. first off if that quote is really a quote than it should be noted where you got it from. doing a text search of the first sentance in the following link gives me nothing so it stands to question the point of it in the question. if there is text there that you want to refer to that should be quoted incase if that site goes down. the question body should also include where your confusion may be coming from because your image and quote seem to just validate Lord Vishnu did have 3 wives so there's no question being asked here

Comment: how it got so many down votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES **Narayana Has Three Wives: Lakshmi, Saraswati, Ganga**

> लक्ष्मीः सरस्वती गङ्‌गा **तिस्रो भार्या हरेरपि** ।
>   प्रेम्णा समास्तास्तिष्ठन्ति सततं हरिसन्निधौ ॥ १७ ॥
>
> Narayana says: O Naarada! Lakshmi, Saraswati and Ganga, **these are Three Wives of Hari Vishnu**,
>   who always abide closest to Vishnu with love and harmony.
>   
>   **Devi Bhagwatam, Ninth Book, Chapter 6, verse 17.**

Comment: The comments under this answer have been deleted.  I would admonish everyone to treat your fellow users with respect.

Comment: But Saraswati is wife of Brahma.... Not of lord Narayan. Even if we consider Saraswati as wife of Narayan, even then why Devi Lakshmi is shown near Narayan in every temple? Why only Lakshmi and Narayan pair in temple? Why never Saraswati and Narayan don't have any pair in temples? Whey Saraswati's statue is alone where as Lakshmi is always shown with Narayan? You answer is full of doubts. And I can't even think that Ganga is wife of Narayan because as per my knowledge Ganga wanted Mahadev as her Husband. Hence its baseless theory.

Comment: @Rishabh Temples have statue of whoever, does not mean it is carved in stone rule. Lakshmi is closest to Vishnu. But it is very true that Hari had three wives. In the Chapter 6 of Ninth book of DeviPuraana, the story is- one day Saraswati started complaining Vishnu, that He loves her less than Ganga and Lakshmi. Later Saraswati started fighting with Ganga. Both Ganga and Saraswati cursed each other. Lakshmi was trying to stop Saraswati.

Comment: @Rishabh ..... Later when Vishnu came, He saw all that. He said- Lakshmi is very good as she maintained peace, so she is closest to me. You Saraswati will remain in half part with me, and in part you go to Brahma. Ganga, you also remain in half part with me, and go to Shiva.

Comment: @AnuragSingh You don't have to explain your religion, your personal philosophy to other users in comments. If someone insists, you can point them to this [answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/424/) ("How does it matter what I profess or practice, the answer or the comment should be judged by its own merit and relevance to the question.") and then flag their comment so mods can take a look at it.

Comment: Ganga and Saraswati were rivers I think. Saraswati here might not be Vani. The dispute rose among Saraswati, Ganga and Kaveri. Ganga ,Kaveri calmed down after sometime but Kaveri didn't. So, she did penance. As a result,we have Sri Rangam temple. @Rishab According to Vedas, Vishnu had three wives but they are Lakshmi, Bhudevi and Nila Devi.

Comment: @SreeCharan you are mentioning some whole other story. Read this [story](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk09ch06.htm) . They were Saraswati, Gangaa, and Lakshmi only.

Comment: @SreeCharan DeviBhagwatam, 9th book, chapter 8, verses 1-3, Nârâyana said :-- **A part of Sarasvatî descended to BharataBhumi owing to the curse of Ganga**... She is named Bhâratî, on account of Her coming to Bhârata; she is called Brâhmî because she is dear to Brahmâ; and **She is called Vânî as She presides over Speech.** Hari is seen everywhere, in tanks, in wells, in running streams (i.e., in Saras). Because He resides in Saras, therefore **Hari is called Sarasvân**. **Vânî is the S'akti of that Sarasvân**; therefore She is **denominated Sarasvatî.**

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. Lord Vishnu had three wives in puranas.

> Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Prakriti Khanda 6.13-21 “…Laksmi, Saraswati and Ganga are the **three wives** of Hari…”
>
> Devi Bhagwatam 9:6:16-21. Nârâyana said :-- Hear, O Nârada! I will now describe that incident, the hearing of which removes all the sins. **Laksmî, Sarasvatî and Gangâ, the three wives** of Hari and all equally loved, remain always close to Hari. One day Gangâ cast side-long glances frequently towards Nârâyana and was eagerly looking at Him, with smile on Her lips. Seeing this, the Lord Nârâyana, startled and looked at Gangâ and smiled also. Laksmî saw that, but she did not take any offence. But Sarasvatî became very angry. Padmâ (Laksmî) who was of Sattva Guna, began to console in various ways the wrathful Sarasvatî; but she could not be appeased by any means. Rather Her face became red out of anger; she began to tremble out of her feelings (passion); Her lips quivered; and She began to speak to Her husband.

Answer (score -2):

Lord Narayanan wife is maha Saraswati her half amsa remained in bramhloka as Saraswati quarter amsa as Saraswati river like Ganga also Sri bhu nila are wife's of para Vasudev in vaikunta vyha in paramapadam there will difference in consort as per Murti difference ,Shakti will be according to murtis.

Saraswati is amsa of maha Saraswati Saraswati is Vidya Lakshmi expansion of Radha Devi ,every purana is true but as per kalpas the deity of Kalpa change sometimes Shakti some times shiva some times Vishu some times Ganesh etc

Comment: Welcome to hinduism site! Please site authentic references to answer!

Comment: The answer looks unclear; visit [answer] and [help] to get how site works. You should site source.